# Vue: Passing a prop to an already embedded component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-props

Basically, I have a 'Display' component that has two embedded components, 'Menu' & 'Feed'. I want my feed to update based on whichever button is clicked within the menu. I'm able to emit the button clicked from my menu component, but how would I go about passing it to the feed component that is already embedded in my template tag?

The Display component template portion looks something like this

```
<template>
   <div>
       <Menu k-bind:options="options"/>
       <Feed/>
   </div>      
</template
```

Options is really just passed into menu just to have it generate the different desired buttons.

The only thing I can think of doing is including `v-on:option-clicked = "updateFeed"` in the Menu tag to have it call an updateFeed method once a button is clicked. I'm not sure how to go about actually updating the feed within this method and that's basically what I'm trying to figure out.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about implementing this, but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you share your menu and feed components code pls

Comment: What is `k-bind`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your `Display` component maintain state for the selected menu option. Bind that to your `Feed` via props and listen for the update event on `Menu`. `Feed` can then [*watch*](https://it.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) for changes to the prop.

#### Display

```html
<Menu :options="options" @option-clicked="option = $event"/>
<Feed :option="option" />
```

```js
data: () => ({
  options: [/* whatever */],
  option: null // holds the selected menu option
})
```

#### Menu (guessing)

```html
<button 
  v-for="option in options"
  @click="$emit('option-clicked', option.value)"
>{{ option.label }}</button>
```

#### Feed

```js
props: ['option'],
methods: {
  updateFeed (selectedOption) {
    // whatever
  }
},
watch: {
  option (selectedOption) {
    this.updateFeed(selectedOption)
  }
}
```